# Accessing MySql Database from PHP file on local host

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, lamp

I am attempting to do a simple connect and SELECT on a LAMP server.

I have made this php code work when connecting to a remote sql database but I cant get it to work with a local database.

```
 <?php
    //I also tried replacing the IP with localhost
    $db = mysql_connect('192.168.1.69','UserIcreated','MyPassword') or die("Connection error");
    $db = mysql_select_db("MyDataBaseName",$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
    
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  MyTableName");
    
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
            echo "Try again";
        }
        else{
            echo "It works";
        }
    ?>
```

You can see here that my server is serving PHP pages(`http://162.226.5.161/workingphp.php`)

But when you try and connect to the above code (`http://162.226.5.161/TestPhp.php`) it errors out. With error 500

When I created the user I also gave the user SELECT privileges on the server

### UPDATE

So the error is happening in line 1:

```
 $db = mysql_connect('192.168.1.69','UserIcreated','MyPassword') or die("Connection error");
```

I commented out the rest of the code and I still get the error. So I believe this to be a configuration issue. Any insight?

Comment: You say "errors out"... what error?

Comment: Also, MySQL databases often limit clients by IP address, without any additional information, my guess is that you didn't whitelist your local IP address.

Comment: what error...,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: sorry its internal server error 500

Comment: `die(myql_error($db))` you are missing `s` in `mysql_`.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller good eye, fixed it with still same error though

Comment: In that case enable error reporting / showing errors / logging errors to file. Error 500 usually means some syntax errors or fatals like call to undefined function.

Comment: Since there is nearly nothing on the first line, do you have `mysql` module in your PHP installation?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller it was resolved. The issue was the module. I thought I installed it but I forgot to use sudo when I did it. must have failed

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you are using valid credential, If all thing are right then make a look on these:

**Error with an .htaccess file**

If you are using a .htaccess on your site, it may be interfering with the web page you are trying to load into your browser. Please double check the .htaccess configuration. Any syntax errors will cause a 500 Internal Server Error message to be displayed instead of your website.

To confirm whether a misconfiguration .htaccess is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error, either remove or rename the .htaccess file temporarily and then try to reload the page.

See also:

Using .htaccess rewrite rules
Using .htaccess files

**PHP Coding Timing Out**

If your PHP script makes external network connections, the connections may time out. If too many connections are attempted and time out, this will cause a "500 Internal Server Error." To prevent these time outs and errors, you'll want to make sure that PHP scripts be coded with some timeout rules. Typically, however, catching a timeout error when connecting to a database or externally to remote resources (example: RSS feeds) are difficult. They, in effect, freeze the script from continuing to run.

Removing any external connections can increase both the performance of your website and decrease the chances of you receiving a "500 Internal Server Error."

**Internal Server Error 500 is not a client or website/web fault...**

Comment: I renamed the htaccess file to htaccess2 and received the same error. The database and server are all on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

You have re-assigned connection resource id in $db in second line

Change $db to $db2 in second line (Database selection function)

Use

```
$db = mysql_connect('192.168.1.69','UserIcreated','MyPassword') 
      or die("Connection error");

$db2 = mysql_select_db("MyDataBaseName",$db) 
      or die(myql_error($db));
```

Instead of

```
$db = mysql_connect('192.168.1.69','UserIcreated','MyPassword') 
      or die("Connection error");

$db = mysql_select_db("MyDataBaseName",$db) 
      or die(myql_error($db));
```

Comment: I made this change and it has the same results

Comment: I did a phpinfo() print at 162.226.5.161/TestPhp.php does this tell you the problem?